# Get selected item text in a ComboBox

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

How to get the currently selected item text (String) in a `ComboBox`?

I am using Ext GWT version 2.2.3 btw.

I have tried `getValueField` and `getSelectedText` but I am getting `null` for both functions.

Comment: I am facing hte same issue, Did you manage to find a solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add a SelectionChangedListener?

Im not familiar with GWT but take alook at [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?118155-Selected-item-in-ComboBox), hope it helps you further.